# Spring Batch - how to use partitioning to read and write data in parallel?

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch application (3.0.7), started via Spring Boot which reads a number of XML files in parallel, process them, and "spit outs" INSERT or UPDATE statements against an Oracle DB.

In order to process the files in parallel, I'm using a `Partitioner`. The job works fine, except for the `JdbcWriter` which seems to be bound only to one thread. Since I'm using a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`, I expected that the Step could run in parallel for the reader, processor and writer. But, it seems that JdbcWriter is always bound to `Thread-1` (I can see that in the logs but also analyzing the database connections, only one connection is active - note that my Datasource is configured to use a pool with 20 connections).

I have annotated the reader, processor and writer as @StepScope. How can I effectively use all the configured threads from the `taskExecutor` to read **AND WRITE** in parallel?

This is an extract from my configuration:

```
@Bean
public Job parallelJob() throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("parallelJob")
            .start(splitFileStep())
            .next(recordPartitionStep())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step recordPartitionStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("factiva-recordPartitionStep")
            .partitioner(recordStep())
            .partitioner("recordStep", recordPartitioner(null)) <!-- this is used to inject some data from the job context
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step recordStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("recordStep")
            .<Object, StatementHolderMap>chunk(1000)
            .reader(recordReader(null)) <!-- this is used to inject some data from the job context
            .processor(recordProcessor) <!-- this is @Autowired, and the bean is marked as @StepScope
            .writer(jdbcItemWriter())
            .build();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemStreamReader recordReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['record-file']}") Resource resource) {
    // THIS IS A StaxEventItemReader
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public JdbcItemWriter jdbcItemWriter() {

    JdbcItemWriter jdbcItemWriter = new JdbcItemWriter();
    jdbcItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
    ...
    return jdbcItemWriter;
}

@Value("${etl.factiva.partition.cores}")
private int threadPoolSize;

@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    if (threadPoolSize == 0) {
        threadPoolSize = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    }
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(threadPoolSize);
    taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();

    return taskExecutor;
}
```

Comment: Check out example https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/partitionFileJob.xml this example reads all the file from directory and processes the file parallely

Comment: Have you confirmed that the `TaskExecutor` is being configured with more than one thread?  Also, how is your `DataSource` configured?  Finally, how have you proven that you're only getting a single thread of execution?

Comment: Hi Michael, the process is running single-threaded. The log statements from the writer or reader are always bound to [thread-1]. I can also see that only one connection (out of 20) from the connection pool is used to execute SQL statements.

Answer (score 5):

I figured out why Spring Batch wasn't using all the configured threads.

First, the Spring configuration for the Partitioner was wrong. 
The original configuration did not set the `gridSize` value and was incorrectly referencing the step to run in partitions.

Second, the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` used in the original configuration doesn't seem to work. Switching to `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` did the trick.

I'm still not sure why the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` didn't work. The javadoc for `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` actually reccommends using a pool to reuse threads.

I'm also not 100% sure I fully understand the implications of setting the `gridSize` value. Currently, I'm setting the `gridSize` to a value which is equal to the numbers of threads used
in the partitioned step. It would be great, if someone could comment on this approach @Michael Minella? :)

This is the correct configuration, for reference.

```
@Bean
public Job parallelJob() throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("parallelJob")
            .start(splitFileStep())
            .next(recordPartitionStep())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step recordPartitionStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("factiva-recordPartitionStep")
            .partitioner(recordStep().getName(), recordPartitioner(null)) <!-- the value for the recordPartitioner constructor is injected at runtime
            .step(recordStep())
            .gridSize(determineWorkerThreads()) <!-- GRID SIZE VALUE MUST BE EQUAL TO THE NUMBER OF THREAD CONFIGURED FOR THE THREAD POOL
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();


}

@Bean
public Step recordStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("recordStep")
            .<Object, StatementHolderMap>chunk(1000)
            .reader(recordReader(null)) <!-- this is used to inject some data from the job context
            .processor(recordProcessor) <!-- this is @Autowired, and the bean is marked as @StepScope
            .writer(jdbcItemWriter())
            .build();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemStreamReader recordReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['record-file']}") Resource resource) {
    // THIS IS A StaxEventItemReader
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public JdbcItemWriter jdbcItemWriter() {

    JdbcItemWriter jdbcItemWriter = new JdbcItemWriter();
    jdbcItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
    ...
    return jdbcItemWriter;
}

@Value("${etl.factiva.partition.cores}")
private int threadPoolSize;

@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("fac-thrd-");

    taskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(determineWorkerThreads());
    return taskExecutor;
}

// threadPoolSize is a configuration parameter for the job
private int determineWorkerThreads() {
    if (threadPoolSize == 0) {
        threadPoolSize = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    }
    return threadPoolSize;

}
```